# PostgreSQL UPSERT with Java PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I decided to try and use PostgreSQL UPSERT in my dao class. When I test this query with DB (7 is an existing record) it updates the game as expected.

```
INSERT INTO games (id, title, description, publisher) 
VALUES (7, 'SomeGame444', 'someDesc', 'SomePublisher')
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE 
SET title = EXCLUDED.title, description = EXCLUDED.description, publisher = 
EXCLUDED.publisher;
```

Howewer new IDs are created with PostgreSQL sequence in the DB. So in my Java application at first I omitted IDs in SQL query and it performed only inserts.

After reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671818/how-can-the-insert-on-conflict-id-do-update-syntax-be-used-with-a-seque) I have added a `default` keyword for indicating sequence values.
And still there is a problem  - when I'm trying to update an existing record it creates a new record with a new ID. I expect it to update a game with an existing ID and create a new one when a game does not have an ID.

Is there something wrong with the PreparedStatement or with the SQL query?

```
public void createOrUpDateGame(Game newGame) {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO games (id, title, description, publisher) " +
                "VALUES (default, ?, ?, ?)\n"  +
                "ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET " +
                "title = EXCLUDED.title, description = EXCLUDED.description, publisher = EXCLUDED.publisher;";

        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        try {
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, newGame.getTitle());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, newGame.getDescription());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, newGame.getPublisher());

            preparedStatement.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Game insert exception");
        } finally {
            JdbcUtils.closeQuietly(preparedStatement);
            JdbcUtils.closeQuietly(connection);
        }

    }
```

Comment: If `id` is auto-generated (through a sequence) there will never be a conflict because the insert statement will always generate a new unique value for `id`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What approach may be used in the situation when UPSERT is not possible due to auto-generated IDs ?

Comment: You need to tell us what the **real** problem is you are trying to solve. How do you detect that a new row should be "identical" to an existing row? Clearly `id` is not the natural primary key of that table, so you need to use  **those** attributes that make up a "unique" game not a generated meaningless number